# Interstial ad not loading after app reinstall or boot in Android API 27 in emulator

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

In my app if I make an app reinstall by drag and drop of the apk in the emulator or start app after restarting the emulator by ad never loads.

I've tried to investigate the cause but the cause just looks like, in this cases, Android "forgets" that the interstitial ad exists, as stupid as it might sound:

```
 interstitialAds.loadAd(adr);


 CountDownTimer mcdf=new CountDownTimer(600000,5000) {

                            @Override
                            public void onTick(long l) {
                                if (interstitialAds.isLoading()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ad loading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                                if (interstitialAds.isLoaded()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Ad loaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFinish() {
                                if (!interstitialAds.isLoaded()) {
                                    interstitialAds.loadAd(adr);


                                }
                            }
                        }.start();
```

What I get is a behavior which displays 3 times "Ad loading" and after that no more Toasts are displayed, on the other hand if I execute the program for a second time I get the expected behavior: "Ad loading" displays 1 or 2 times and the rest of the time "Ad loaded" displays periodically.

My bets now are into that this is an emulator bug, but maybe I'm missing something.

I think the best way to help me with this question would be for someone who has an API 27 physical device to check that an interstitialAd loads under the described situations (app reinstall while the previous one is still installed and after a boot).

The interstitial ad is defined this way in my manifest, just in case that were to have any effect:

```
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            tools:replace="android:theme"
          />
```

Comment: You are assigning theme to the activity and immediately replacing it. Weird.

Comment: Also after loading ad -> Count down timer, if finished then load the ad again. What do you actually want to do? You are loading ad two times.

Comment: @Gourav, don't mind that, that was a test to check that if it wasn't loaded in the CountDownTimer, it might work if loaded again, but it doesn't work, the important part is that on the described situations the process of loading ad "seems to disappear"

Comment: Then you can try the app on a real device.

Comment: @Gourav, it works in a pair of real ones, but I don't have a real one with API 27, that's the reason I'm asking.